# Sql query based on same column values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

i have a table like below

```
encno  payername payment adjustment
1        ahp1      -0.00   -180
1        map1      -112    -220
2        ahp2       0.20    0.23
2        map1       null    null
3        ahp3       0.20    0.23
3        map2       null    null
```

my query is to get the encounter no where map is null. but along with that encounter no, it should also display the ahp record. coz ahp and map will have same enc no as shown in example.
pls help

expected result

```
encno     payername   payment adjustment
    2        ahp2       0.20    0.23
    2        map1       null    null
    3        ahp3       0.20    0.23
    3        map2       null    null
```

Comment: We love that you're here and please clean up your question. You have provided no sample sql to work from and no expected results.

Comment: i dont have the sample sql currenly , i just use the where condition on payer_name and payment and adjustment.

Comment: what column are you referring to by "map"? what are you referring to by "ahp"? you are referring to things that aren't clearly represented in your example table

Comment: those are payer names. so for one encounter no, there will be ahp and map payer names. i need to display both ahp and map where map values for payment and adjustment will be null

Comment: i am wondering how to select both records for one encounter where values will be different for columns payername, payment and adjustment, i need to select only those where map payer name in that encounter will be null.

Comment: just updated my answer so it should display both records as requested

Answer (score 0):

You get the `ecno`s that you need with this query:

```
select ecno from tablename
where payment is null and adjustment is null
```

So you can use it with the `IN` operator:

```
select * from tablename
where ecno in (
  select ecno from tablename
  where payment is null and adjustment is null
)
```

Comment: thanks forpas, but it wont get the ahp record for that encounter no. see, enc 2 it has ahp2 and map1. it should display both these records for encounter 2.

Comment: It will display both rows because it selects by id. The subquery returns 2 and 3. So the query will return all rows with ecno 2 and 3

Comment: my query is like if encounter = 2, check payer_name = map. if payment = null, adjusmtent = null , display. if encounter = 2. if payer_name = ahp. display as it is all column values.

Comment: thanks forpas, for now its looking okay, i will ask, if not working, need to be tested.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are requesting, you want the records where the `payername` is like `map` and the `payment` and `adjustment` columns are `NULL` and you also want the record that has the same `encno` number but the `payername` is like `ahp`. If that's the case, this query will do that:

```
SELECT mapTable.*,
    ahpTable.* 
FROM #your table name# AS mapTable
JOIN #your table name# AS ahpTable ON aphTable.encno = mapTable.encno
    AND ahpTable.payername <> mapTable.payername
WHERE mapTable.payername LIKE 'map%'
    AND mapTable.payment IS NULL
    AND mapTable.adjustment IS NULL
ORDER BY mapTable.encno, ahpTable.encno
```

Comment: i dont have two table like ahp table and map table. i just have one table with both these records. so out of those, i need the encounters in which ahp wont be null and map will be null. ahp is primary insurance and map is secondary, so need to get those encounter no, in which primary paid but not secondary

Comment: it's the same table, i'm joining the same table to itself so i can define different criteria. the table aliased `mapTable` selects the records where the `payername` is like `map` and the `payment` and `adjustment` columns are null and the table aliased as `ahpTable` selects the records from the table that have the same `encno` but the `payername` is like `ahp`, so all you need to do is plug in the name of your table for both of the instances of `#your table name#` and the query will work. try it.